# Make favorites always visible in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, favorites

Vista introduced the favorites in the navigation pane of Windows Explorer. In Windows 7 I immediately noticed that the favorites don't have a separate pane at the top anymore.

[image: A comparison.]

So to access the favorites (which I do *a lot*, I love that feature!) I always have to scroll to the top first which is quite annoying.

**Is there any way to restore the old behavior?** I can't believe that they went a step backwards here.

Answer (score 3):

I think Microsoft has still not provided a tweak for this, as [**people are still ranting about it**](http://www.windows7taskforce.com/view/2972). A possible fix, if you don't require the entire expanded folders when you are in a directory, you can turn off "**Expand to Current Folder**". This should keep your Navigation pane smaller so it doesn't have the ability to scroll down. See Navigation -> Folder options.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I usually just drag and drop shortcuts into the favourites section win win7 the same way that you do in vista

Answer (score 0):

Not a fix for this oversight, but an option is to use [QTTabBar](http://qttabbar.wikidot.com/).  I's a freeware add-on that places folder tabs on the top of the WE window, and selectively allows you to lock them in place.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an answer to the question